# In T-SQL, does OUTPUT INTO only work with table variables?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to retrieve the latest identity value from an INSERT statement.  Ignoring the question of which of OUTPUT, @@IDENTITY, or SCOPE_IDENTITY() is a better method, can I use OUTPUT to directly insert into an INT variable, or do I have to OUTPUT into table variable then select from that?

i.e. can I do something like (I know this does not work):

```
DECLARE @NewId INT

INSERT INTO MyTable (foo)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @NewID
VALUES ('bar');
```

Or do I always have to do:

```
DECLARE @NewId TABLE (NewId INT)
DECLARE @NewIdAsInt INT

INSERT INTO MyTable (foo)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @NewID
VALUES ('bar');

SET @NewIdAsInt = (SELECT TOP(1) NewId FROM @NewId)
```

Comment: NO, you should be able to `OUTPUT INTO ....` a temp or a permanent table as well. But it has to be a **table** - you cannot output into a single variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OUTPUT INTO must refer to a table of some kind - a table variable, temporary or other table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

What is wrong with Scope_Identity() anyway?

Comment: I keep seeing comments that OUTPUT is now the preferred way of returning values from operations.  Someone also pointed to this bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779.  I probably wouldn't run into this problem, but still good to use best practices, right?

Comment: Scope_Identity() doesn't work if you want multiple columns or non-identity columns.

Answer (score -1):

According to Microsoft Books on-line you can capture updated info into variable names if one and only one record is affected by the update statement. I tried that and it works fine. Here is my test code. Try it for yourself and let me know.

```
DECLARE @PreValue   VARCHAR(100),
        @PostValue  VARCHAR(100)

UPDATE t
SET @PreValue = t.Ter_Desc, @PostValue = t.Ter_Desc += ' Example Update'
FROM [dbo].[Dim_Territory] AS t
WHERE t.Ter_ID = 5

SELECT COALESCE(@PreValue, 'NV') AS 'Pre', COALESCE(@PostValue, 'NV') AS 'Post'
```

Comment: This does not answer the stated question: can scalar variables (as opposed to table variables) be loaded using the OUTPUT INTO clause.